# A loop routine in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

Suppose, I have written **6 functions** defined as objects named **A, B,...F** in R.

Now, I want the below package to **run 6 times**, each time putting one of the 6 functions' names, say, A, in front of "***fun=***" and putting a file name in front of "***file=***". File names may be ***1.docx*** for **A**,    ***2.docx*** for **B**,...,  ***6.docx*** for **F**.

Here is the package I want to run 6 times (note that at each run, only "**fun=**" & "**file=**" need to change):

```
library('ReporteRs')
doc = docx()
doc = addPlot(doc, fun = A, vector.graphic = TRUE) 
writeDoc(doc, file = "1.docx")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a simple `lapply` using `seq_along` for number iteration:

```
funclist <- list(A, B, C)

lapply(seq_along(funclist), function(i){
   doc = docx()
   doc = addPlot(doc, fun = funclist[[i]], vector.graphic = TRUE) 
   writeDoc(doc, file = paste0(i, ".docx"))
})
```

Comment: Thanks, when I add other arguments (e.g., fontname_serif="Time New Roman") to the addPlot code line the procedure seems not to produce the 6 output file for the 6 functions.